# Allocate ram memory to docker engine on ubuntu

Tags: docker, ram, sentry

I'm setting sentry using docker on ubuntu, and when I tried to run install.sh I encountered this message

```
FAIL: Expected minimum RAM available to Docker to be 2400 MB but found 983 MB
```

I know how to allocate ram memory using GUI, but since I'm working on ubuntu server using ssh I would like to know how to allocate ram using cli, not allocating memory by container, just allocating ram to docker engine.

Comment: There's no such thing; unless you use something like `docker run -m` to limit it, any container can use all available host memory on native Linux.

Comment: @DavidMaze yeah just realized that native linux has not enough ram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, there is no limit on how much memory or CPU a container can use. It can use as much as the host’s kernel scheduler allows. So this error caused by not enough memory from native linux

Comment: How do I increase my ram from the native machine?